# How does Apple/Google/other calendar see post-midnight?

Tags: dates, time, calendar, google, apple

As extension to my other question: [Time after midnight, user experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/62806/time-after-midnight-user-experience)

Does Apple/Google/other calendars see post-midnight as very *early* this day, or very *late* this day?

I can't test it myself, but I'm curious (and confused)

If I set a date to be Monday the 1st of September 2014 at night 12:59 AM, will this actually be handled (military correctly) as Monday very early *morning*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I set a date to be Monday the 1st of September 2014 at 12:59 PM, will this actually be handled as tuesday very early morning?

No, this would be treated as Monday afternoon, just before 1pm.

Early morning on Tuesday would be Tuesday 12:59am in 12-hour format or 00:59 in 24-hour format. And while it's true that people might also describe that as "Monday night", in my opinion, you have to stick to describing it as Tuesday unless you write it in speech-like form and use the word "night".

## Guidelines

- The crossing point from Monday to Tuesday is midnight (00:00)
- The crossing point from AM to PM is noon (12:00).
- Midnight is the first instant of "AM" (edit: SOME places, [not all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight)), and can be written 00:00 in 24-hour format or 12am in 12-hour format.
- Noon is the first instant of "PM" and can be written 12:00 in 24-hour format or 12pm in 12-hour format.

## Google Calendar

When specifying a time for an event in Google Calendar, the time inputs are in 24-hour format so it's fairly unambiguous what time you are entering. If you enter a 12-hour format, such as "1:00", it corrects on blur to '01:00". Likewise "1pm" is corrected to "13:00".

[image: Google Calendar]

## Apple Calendar

Apple Calendar behaves the same way:

[image: Apple Calendar]

Comment: Ok. A bit odd, but good they stick to the same day. So how do you choose (with AM/PM) the hour between midnight and 1 o clock at night? 00.30 AM? (doesn't exist) 12.30AM? (that's daytime)

Comment: Could it be that you are using 24-hour format on OS? (I see you have "14:00"). If so, I think AM/PM is ignored, and 12.59 noon is assumed..

Comment: Yes, you'd choose 12:30am, and that does exist! The other 12:30, the one after noon, is 12:30pm.

Comment: By the way "Midnight is the first instant of AM" is false.. 1 o clock AM is first instant of AM (one hour later)

Comment: Yes my Google Calendar is indeed set to display times as "13:00" rather than "1pm", but the inputs accept both formats and handle them the same.

Comment: 12.30 PM is a valid time. It's half hour after midnight, not yet AM. Calendar does not accept this?

Comment: If I type "12am" when creating an event in Google Calendar, it is created as midnight. And if I type "12pm" it is created as noon. See the section "Confusion at noon and midnight" here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock

Comment: The hour after midnight but before 1 o' clock, is it called AM or PM? I would say PM, so would wikipedia. Only in 24 hour format is midnight reset to start. In AM/PM it is reset one hour later.. so confusing

Comment: 12.15 PM = 00:15 (24-hour)

Comment: In the UK, that hour is AM. But I'm starting to realise this could be different for different cultures, e.g. http://longtailworld.blogspot.co.uk/2006/04/japan1212am-is-noon-in-japan.html appears that most agree 00:00 or 00:01 is the start of 'am', but some call noon 12:00am.

Comment: Even more confusing.. ok so in UK the new day (after midnight) starts with 12:00AM?

Comment: Yes, although it's less confusing to say 'midnight' or '00:00'. There is a lot of ambiguity around whether to describe noon and midnight as AM or PM.

Comment: Hehe.. the twilight zone ;) So what happens when you input 12:45AM in calendar?

Comment: In Google Calendar, it accepts it, and creates the event 45 minutes after midnight.

Comment: Ok. I see I also thought the first hour after midnight was PM.. guess not. Anyway, thanks. This can drive a person crazy ;)

Comment: I'm sure you're not the only person that thinks so!

Comment: I personally think (hope) AM/PM countries will soon upgrade to 24-hour format like most of the world ;) They/you use it for trains, planes etc. Why not everything else? It's also called "military time" because it's exact and without the same ambiguity